# Muliple line move and duplicate in PhpStorm

Tags: netbeans, ide, line, shortcut, phpstorm

I migrated from NetBeans to PhpStorm.
How can I change multiple line duplication and movement method in PhpStorm to NetBeans method?
(PhpStorm requires full selection of lines to move or dublicate)

update:
Consider two following line"

```
   lin1 --------------
   lin2 ++++++++++++++
```

if you completely select both line and press ctrl+d :
in NetBeans you will get:

```
lin1 --------------
lin2 ++++++++++++++
lin1 --------------
lin2 ++++++++++++++
```

in PhpStorm you will get:

```
  lin1 --------------
  lin2 ++++++++++++++lin1 --------------
  lin2 ++++++++++++++
```

now consider two following line ({}=selection bound)

```
   lin1 ---------{-----
   lin2 +++++++++}+++++
```

if you partially select both line and press ctrl+d :
in NetBeans you will get:

```
   lin1 ---------{-----
   lin2 +++++++++}+++++
   lin1 ---------{-----
   lin2 +++++++++}+++++
```

in PhpStorm you will get:

```
   lin1 ---------{-----
   lin2 +++++++++-----
   lin2 +++++++++}+++++
```

In NetBeans ctrl+e will delete multiple line but ctrl+y will not act on multiple line.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly multiple lines movement/duplication works in NetBeans without selection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ctrl+D is mapped to the 'Duplicate Line or Block' action that does exactly what you've mentioned (copy selected text right after selection end).

What you need to do is to [reassign](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) the shortcut to the 'Duplicate Lines' action that provides the desired behavior.

Denis

Comment: I could not find 'Duplicate Lines' action. I am using 2.1.2 version.

Comment: @Reza, this feature should be available starting from 3.0 version, you can already try the EAP version: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP.

Comment: For the googlers: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/adding-deleting-and-moving-lines.html#procedure%0A______to_duplicate_a_line_or_fragmentduplicating_lines